# AS3 Picking a random object from an Array with certain conditions

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm looking for the fastest way to pick a random object that has a certain condition (from an array).

In the example below I have a multidimensional array, 50 * 50 that contains objects. I want to pick a random object from that array but that object needs to have a size larger than 100.

```
while (object.size <= 100)
{
    attempts++;
    object = grid_array[Math.round(Math.random() * 49)][Math.round(Math.random() * 49)];
}
```

Currently I have tested this and in some instances it takes over 300+ attempts. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: If you want to pick a random object that has a size larger than 100 you need to change the `while` condition to: while( object.size <= 100 ). The time that it takes depends of how much objects have a size larger than 100 in your `Array`.

Comment: Sorry, that was only for demonstration purposes, I have amended my post, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is first filter the source array to extract only valid candidates, then return a random one (if there are any).

For example:

```
function getRandomObject(grid_array:Array, minSize:Number):Object {
    var filtered:Array = [];
    for(var i:int = 0; i < grid_array.length; i++){
        var inner:Array = grid_array[i];
        for(var ii:int = 0; ii < inner.length; ii++){
            var object:Object = inner[ii];
            if(object.size >= minSize){
                filtered.push(object);
            }
        }
    }
    return filtered.length ? filtered[int(Math.random() * filtered.length)] : null;
}

// example:
var object:Object = getRandomObject(grid_array, 100);
if(object){
    // do stuff with `object`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I asked if you need the indexes because you could do this with `RegExps` and the `JSON` Class (Flash Player 11). With this example I stored the indexes of the objects:

**Create random multidimensional Array to test the function**

```
//---I stored a variable size and the indexes inside the Object
//---Size variable will be numbers between 0 and 500
var array:Array = [];

var i;
var j;
var size:uint = 50;
var obj:Object;

for(i = 0; i < size; i++){

    array[i] = [];

    for(j = 0; j < size; j++){

        obj = new Object();
        obj.size = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
        obj.files = i;
        obj.columns = j;

        array[i][j] = obj;      

    }

}
```

**Method to get random Object with size property bigger than 100**

```
//---I'll use to search the object a JSON string
var str:String = JSON.stringify(array);

//---Function to get the random Object
function getRandom():Object{

    //---RegExp to search object with size between 100 and 500
    var reg:RegExp = /\{[^\}]*"size":(?:10[1-9]|1[1-9]\d|[2-5]\d\d)[^\}]*\}/g;

    //---Get all matches
    var matches:Array = str.match(reg);

    //---Return a random match converted to object
    //---If no match founded the return will be null
    return matches ? JSON.parse( matches[Math.floor(Math.random() * matches.length)] ) : null;

}
```